# Django: Sending data from backend to frontend without page refresh

Tags: django, ajax, backend

I am developing a Website with django.
Now, let's say I have a database where values can change at any time.
Every time the DB changes, I want to execute a function (no problem with that) and update some data I passed to a template without a page refresh.

At first, I thought about AJAX, but as it seems an AJAX-Request must be started from the frontend, right?

Long story short:
What I want specifically is to update some CSS depending on some data changes in the backend without any page refresh.

Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is can be achieved using channels and websockets please take a look in [this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="here2">
...Your Content...
</div>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here");
      }, 1000);
    });

</script>
```